# How to see django object query speed

Tags: python, django

I would like to test different ways of text searching in django models with different functions. Is there a way to print in the console or in the template how long does it take to query the database? Thanks in advance
(Might not be necessary but still: These are the 3 functions I want to test the speed of.)

```
def first_results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.POST.get('query')
        results = Page.objects.search(query)
        return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': results})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')


def second_results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.POST.get('query')
        results = Page.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'content')).filter(
            search=query
        )
        return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': results})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')


def third_results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.POST.get('query')
        results = Page.objects.filter(
            Q(title__contains=query) | Q(content__contains=query)
        )
        return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': results})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: You can obtain data about the latest query with `from django.db import connections;
connections['default'].queries[-1]`. This is a dictionary with a`'time'` key that contains the time in seconds to process the request.

Comment: Note that your queries are only performed when you actually render the template, so not inside of your views. If you want to force the querysets to be evaluated in your views in order to log the time they take, you should wrap your queryset in a `list()`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are doing this in your development environment, i'd recommend the Django debug toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Django Debug Toolbar; it shows you the SQL Statements, the execution time in a detailed way (and much more):

https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want a better profiling of queries, I recommend you to use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar),

If you want something simple, use [Django DB Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) in your console. [Follow this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/uzhyca/quickly-setup-sql-query-logging-django).

Answer (score 0):

You can log all the queries to console and then compare their speed. To enable logging you need this in your `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        }
    }
}
```